# Is it allowed to instantiate a module inside always_comb block in system verilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Is it allowed to instantiate a module inside `always_comb` block in system verilog?

```
always_comb 
begin
   OR OR1 (.Y(A), .A(Z), 
end
```

Comment: if you really want to use conditional hardware, convert your module to task or function and call it conditionally. It increase your hardware resources but will meet your requirement.

Comment: Is there any particular reason your trying todo this rather than just instantiating it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, your code is incomplete. Obviously, a *two-input* **OR gate** requires three connections.

In verilog, when you are **instantiating** a module, that means you are adding extra **hardware** to the board.

This hardware **must be** added **before simulation starts**(i.e. at compile time). Here, you can not add/remove hardware at each clock pulse.

Once instantiated, the module is executed/checked for **each timestamp** of simulation, till the end.

So to execute any module, just instantiate it, providing the required inputs to it (and add the always block in the sub-module itself, if necessary).

```
// Simply instantiate module
OR OR1 (.Y(A), .A(Z), .B(M));
```

**Either way**, you can add a combinational block to the current module itself:

```
// Directly use ORing
always_comb begin
  A = Z | M;
end
```

More information on **instantiation** can be obtained from [Verilog Module Instantiation](http://verilog.renerta.com/mobile/source/vrg00027.htm), [Instantiating Modules and Primitives](http://support.ema-eda.com/search/eslfiles/default/main/sl_legacy_releaseinfo/staging/sl3/release_info/psd142/veriaref/chap10.html), [Structural Modelling](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CCkQFjACahUKEwiiwbmgq5LJAhUEJI4KHcE-BGY&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wiley.com%2Flegacy%2Fwileychi%2Fmblin%2Fsupp%2Fstudent%2FLN06HierarchicalModeling.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFafpIm8Z2BwL2O_k0hXVqzSVxVYA&bvm=bv.107467506,d.c2E) links.